# How to replace comma with a dot in the number and delete € symbol in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, structured-data

i have a price valor (for example 3,45€) how can i create a function that could replace and create a dynamic output with the dot in place of the comma? and without the "€". (in this example 3.45)
thank you

Comment: Have you done any research so far? Replacing characters and extracting numbers from strings are both pretty trivial tasks with many existing and easy to find solutions.

Comment: `price = price.replace(/^(\d+),(\d+)€$/,'$1.$2');` for instance

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
let price = "3,45€";
price = price.split(',').join('.').substring(0, price.length - 1);
```